# IE11 submit not recognizing elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

Firstly, I am sorry to anyone that finds this post more than a little trivial, but I am currently sratching my hair out on, at first sight, is a form posting matter.

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 6 application which is running perfectly in Chrome and Edge, but recently, I was informed that it would also need to be able to run on IE11.

My issue is when a submit the form.

```
 $("#js-form").on("submit", function (e) {
     document.getElementById("DefinitionID-error").style.visibility = "hidden";
     document.getElementById("DefinitionID-error").textContent = "<some text>";
     document.getElementById("DefinitionID-error").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
```

The code appears to execute in the IE11 debugger, with no error messages, but on screen the original text held in #DefinitionID-error does not change.

The version of IE11 I am using, is the super special version that ships with Windows 10.

Other code I have tried include:

```
 $("#js-form").on("submit", function (e) {
     $("#DefinitionID-error").hide();
     $("#DefinitionID-error").text("<some text>");
     $("#DefinitionID-error").show();
 }

 $("#js-form").on("submit", function (e) {
     $("#DefinitionID-error").html("<span id='DefinitionID-error'>Some text</span>");
 }

 $("#js-form").on("submit", function (e) {
     document.querySelector("#DefinitionID-error").textContent = "<some text>";
 }

 $("#js-form").on("submit", function (e) {
     document.querySelector("#DefinitionID-error").innerHTML = "<span id='DefinitionID-error'>some text</span>";
 }
```

All of these work in Chrome and funnily enough Edge, but not in IE11.

**NEW** Example that also does not work

```
 $("#js-form").on("submit", function (e) {    
     $("#DefinitionID-error").hide();
     $("#DefinitionID-error").text("Some text");
     $("#DefinitionID-error").show();
 }
```

**UPDATE**

If I take the jQuery code, or the javascript code and run it in the debugger in IE11. it works, so it must have something to do with the submission, maybe.

Comment: Why you mix jQuery and VanilaJS? `document.querySelector("#DefinitionID-error")` => `document.getElementById()` => `$("#DefinitionID-error")`

Comment: Please show the related HTML as well, then we have a chance of making a demo which reproduces the problem

Comment: Why do you hide and show something two lines apart? The user will never see the hidden version because that is never going to get painted. In any case, to debug this, use `e.preventDefault()` to stop form submission and see what happends. I would also remove the line that is hiding the text since that's not doing anything

Comment: juan, I actually need it to post, but I have tried by using the preventDefault and still the same thing happens. IE11 executes the code, but does not show any changes or errors.

Comment: It would be very useful to see the code that submits the form, and the markup for the form itself, because I cannot reproduce this error using a simple form with a `<button type="submit">`

Comment: You have to submit it programatically. Try calling `setTimetout( () => this.submit(), 2000)` so you have time to see it on the screen.

Comment: Please give us the relevant HTML as well

Answer (score 0):

I made a test with code below on windows 10, Internet Explorer 11. It is working fine on Ie 11.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#clk").click(function(){
   $("#js-form").submit();
   console.log(222); 
  });
  
  
   $("#js-form").on("submit", function (e) {  
   console.log("start");  
 
     $("#DefinitionID-error").hide();
     $("#DefinitionID-error").val("Some text");
     $("#DefinitionID-error").show();
    alert("Form submitted");
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>



<button id="clk">Click me to submit form</button>


<form id="js-form">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="DefinitionID-error" name="DefinitionID-error" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 


</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]